# Get encoded JSON array with jQuery, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Good afternoon developers,

The last couple weeks I've been working on Ajax with jQuery, since it's a major element on modern websites nowadays.
However, I simply can't retrieve an encoded JSON array, from my PHP file with jQuery. Because the most basic ability I at least should possess is reading out Mysql data with AJAX.

I've tried `$.getJSON(url, data, response)` , `dataType: 'json'` , but neighter solutions worked out, and I've also visited several websites including various StackOverflow questions...

This is the regarding PHP code that retrieves data through Mysql and converts it into a JSON object array:

```
  <?php //ajaxIndex.php

    include 'connectionFile1.php' ; //connection file 

                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users" ;

                if ($result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1) ) {

                    $resultsSql1 = mysqli_num_rows($result1) ;

                    $return_array = array();

                    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
                        $row_array['userName'] = $row1['userName'];
                        $row_array['email'] = $row1['email'];

                        //$return_array[] = $row1 ;

                        array_push($return_array, $row_array);
                    }


                   //encode the mysql array

                    print json_encode($return_array); // this array is correctly encoded




                 }

        ?>
```

This is the jQuery code that should properly retrieve and assimilate the JSON object array:

```
<script>

//$(document).ready(fetchData) ;

$("#button").click(function () {


    $.ajax({ 

        url: "ajaxIndex.php",      
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json' ,                
        success: function(response){ 

            console.log(response) ;
            $.each(response, function() {

                        console.log(this.userName + "<br>") ;
                        console.log(this.email) ;

            }) ;

        }

    });


}) ;


//window.setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);

 </script>
```

Thank you dudes in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(response) ;` ?

Comment: can you provide us with the console.log output ?

Comment: `console.log(response) ;` is used to inspect whether Ajax properly retrieved the json object array. So I can see if it executed correctly...

Comment: yeah but what does it show ?

Comment: Well... the `console.log(response)` actually results in no output, that is also a problem. My console log is simply empty even when I click on the button.

Comment: Check your ajaxIndex.php code!

Comment: I did and it executes properly... When I print the Array it shows this JSON: `[{"userName":"jelle","email":"jelle.oudega@gmail.com"},{"userName":"jelle2","email":"jelle.oudega@gmail.com"},{"userName":"jelle3","email":"jelle.oudega@gmail.com"}]` This array is the result of my MySQL query. `print json_encode($return_array);`

Comment: Do you see this JSON appear in the browser if you type in the URL "ajaxIndex.php" directly?

Comment: Yes I do see the array appear when I type in "ajaxIndex.php"

Comment: Are you sure the button click handler is executing when you click? Can you put a `console.log('test 1, 2, 3')` here and there (with different text) to see execution arrives where it should?

Comment: Yes for a 100%. I just checked and the code outputs "123". Thus, the regarding function is triggerd

Comment: There must be nothing else than JSON in the response.  Any chance that the file generates an extra message (if yes, make sure it doesn't)?  Otherwise I don't see any error

Comment: Press F12 and check the Network tab when pressing the button. Inspect the result there to check if the result is OK or not.

Comment: Thank you all guys... luckily I have solved the deal, finally. Turns out that the PHP file didn't generate a correct JSON array.